# String to DATETIME with TimeZone

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, csv, ssis, flat-file

I have an SSIS package which pulls in a flat file from a survey system.  One of the fields in the flat file is called start_date.  It comes in format "04/29/2015 10:09:41 AM PDT"

Executing...

```
SELECT Start_Date = CAST(Start_Date AS DATETIME)
```

Results in...

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

PDT is causing the issue as when I remove it manually the query is fine.  My question is a bit of scalability question.  Sure I can hard code it and remove the PDT.  Is there a simple way to remove this without being specific to string replacement or left(x) or hard coding a PDT removal?  I am not seeing it.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Time zone will always follow the last space, whatever it would be. So here is a generic way you can chop it off. You can set up a lookup for time zones, if you like, at that point.

```
DECLARE @dtstr NVARCHAR(50) = '04/29/2015 10:09:41 AM PDT'
DECLARE @tzpos INT = CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@dtstr)) --find last space
DECLARE @dt DATETIME2 = LEFT(@dtstr,LEN(@dtstr)-@tzpos) --truncate at last space

SELECT @dt
```